# VB.NET - List.Contains always returns false when it should be true

Tags: vb.net, list, visual-studio, object, contains

I am more of a C# developer, and I am stuck on trying to implement something on my visual basic code;
TL;DR is I have a database table which holds all the IDs of Employees that have gone through a process. I want to be able to get those into a list, and see if any of the current members going through this process exist on this list, and if they do remove those members so they don't get reprocessed. The database table returns an object called of type "ProcessedTermedMember" which is a custom object with three string propertys (ID, FirstName, LastName)

I basically have this code here, which is returning false... I know that it is looking to see the Reference is equal by default with contains, so it would only be true when it is the exact same object, vs an object where all properties are the same. How can I override this?

Here is my code:

```
            Dim termedMembers = (From ec In db.ECs
                                 Where ec.AccountTypeCode = "WCS"
                                 Where ec.AccountStatus = 5
                                 Select ec).ToList()

Dim processedTermMembers = (From p In db.ProcessedTermedMembers
                                        Select p).ToList()

            For Each member In termedMembers
                Dim term As ProcessedTermedMember = New ProcessedTermedMember With {.EmployeeID = member.EmployeeID, .FirstName = member.EmployeeFirstName, .LastName = member.EmployeeLastName}

                If processedTermMembers.Contains(term) Then
                    termedMembers.Remove(member)
                End If
            Next
```

This 'If Then' statement in the loop always returns "false" how can I get it to return true if all properties in the "term" variable are equal to the properties of one of the list items in "processedTermMembers"?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Notes, example and Remarks section of [List<T>.Contains(T)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains). Note the implementation of [IEquatable<T>.Equals(T)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1.equals). If you don't provide a custom comparer, only the references are compared, so none will ever be equal to another in this context.

Comment: @Jimi how would I go about creating a custom comparer for the object and its properties in Visual Basic?

Comment: Yes. Implement the `IEquatable<T>` interface where T is your `ProcessedTermedMember` object. Override the properties, methods, and operators as shown in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1.equals?view=net-5.0#examples) example.

Comment: These examples are for C#, I am having trouble finding a way to implement this in Visual Basic, but I will take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work for a couple of reasons, but namely because you are attempting to modify a collection inside of a For/Each loop.

The simplest solution would be to move the declaration of `termedMembers` to after the declaration of `processedTermMembers` and to add an additional where clause to `termedMembers`:

```vb
Dim processedTermMembers = (From p In db.ProcessedTermedMembers
                            Select p).ToList()

Dim termedMembers = (From ec In db.ECs
                     Where ec.AccountTypeCode = "WCS" AndAlso ec.AccountStatus = 5 AndAlso Not processedTermMembers.Any(Function(term) term.EmployeeID = ec.EmployeeID AndAlso term.FirstName = ec.EmployeeFirstName AndAlso term.LastName = ec.EmployeeLastName)).ToList()
```

What the modified LINQ statement does is pull in the records from `db.ECs` where the AccountTypeCode is not "WCS", the AccountStatus is not 5, and is not in the `processedTermMembers` collection.

Comment: Thank you for this, the "AndAlso" for the ec.AccountStatus and the "AndAlso Not" returns a syntax error, i replaced it with "Where" and it worked, but when i run it i get the following error:

System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to create a constant value of type 'TestingApp.ProcessedTermedMember'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.'

Comment: Can you try like this way: `... AndAlso Not processedTermMembers.Any(Function(term) ec.EmployeeID.Equals(term.EmployeeID) AndAlso ...`

Comment: Tried this, I get "Syntax Error" on the "AndAlso" that's not inside the .Any().

Comment: @Arkayik I did free-type this example, so you may need to adjust the syntax a bit. If you add all the conditions on a single line, does it work?

Comment: Wow, yes. Putting it on one line fixed the issue, thank you this was an amazing help. 

instead of making a link statement for the processedTermMembers list, I just changed it to "AndAlso Not db.ProcessedTermedMembers.Any()" to reference the actual live table, and not the list object. That worked amazing, with much less code. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No problem! I updated my example to include the where conditions on a single line.

Answer (score 1):

Just some modification into @David code :

```
    Dim processedTermMembers = (From p In db.ProcessedTermedMembers
                                Select p).ToList()

    Dim termedMembers = (From ec In db.ECs
                         Where (ec.AccountTypeCode = "WCS" _
                             AndAlso ec.AccountStatus = 5 _
                             AndAlso Not (processedTermMembers.Any(Function(term) ec.EmployeeID.Equals(term.EmployeeID) AndAlso ec.EmployeeFirstName.Equals(term.FirstName) AndAlso ec.EmployeeLastName.Equals(term.LastName))))).ToList()
```